# A query regarding the Max3SAT Approximation Algorithm's Application

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, np-hard, approximation, sat-solvers

Its known that a polynomial time Approximation Algorithm that satisfies 3MaxSAT in 7/8+e clauses implies P=NP. If given that the given 3MaxSAT is satisfiable, it is still difficult to find a 7/8+e clause satisfiability in Polynomial Time.

After learning quiet a few Max3SAT Approximation Algorithms I am still very unsure regarding the real world applications of such inexact algorithms other than theoretical perspective (unlike 3SAT).

Can someone point of few of the real world application areas.

Comment: SAT can represent real world constraints on problems and not satisfying all the clauses can represent a "relaxation" of the problem that might be "good enough". so its more application specific of real world encodings of MaxSAT etc....